# Svn or Git client (or plugin) to find missing or broken files

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

Very often while using Svn (or other version control system) there is a problem programmer commits some changes and breaks a build. For example, because:

- some files were created, but not add under version control
- changes were made in one folder, but programmer thought that it was other folder and committed it
- files in a few subfolders were changed, but only one folder was committed
- programmer changed some code, but didn't compile it ("because it was so easy changes!")
- etc.

Broken build is bad thing - wasted time, interrupted work of other people and it would be great to avoid it. So I am looking for some svn (git?) client\tool\plugin, which has hook "before commit", where it can check a few basic things, like:

- if folder contains files of some type (let's say "cpp") not under
  version control - show a warning
- if folder contains project file (from VS or other IDE) and this project file contains some references to files not under version control - show a warning
- if folder contains project file and files of some type (let's again say "cpp")
  tool should (optionally) try to build this file using settings from project file and show warning if file not compiles

I tried to find such tool - but without success. Now I have idea to create such tool myself (with plugin-based architecture to be able easy add support for new project types, file types and version control types). But before start working on this tool I want to ask - maybe I missed something and such tool already exists?

Thank you

Comment: If you're after help creating hooks for those specific cases, might be worth asking them in their own questions. Otherwise it might be helpful to clarify that your question is about a finding a library of pre-built hooks or hook-related functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration server, e.g. Jenkins. Because it is not a job for a version control system.

Sometimes build takes at least several minutes or even hours (+tests). It is very bad practice to force developers do commits so slowly.

Also, not added/not deleted files should not be an issue at all while you keep working copy tidy. If you have all `.gitignore` set up, `--assume-unchaged` provided, then `git status` will show nothing after commit. So, just teach developers to care about working copy hygiene, it helps a lot.

Comment: I use continuous integration (CruiseControl) and broken builds on it is the main reason of this question. Complete build of our product with all subcomponents takes near 1 hour and it is very bad to see after 1 hour that build was broken because of missing files.  You say that "it is not job for a version control system". Why? Having code in trunk in good state - it is main job for version control, I think. Maybe only a last one of my ideas ("build before commit") is out of scope - and I wrote that is optional. But even this build can be done only for new\changed files- so it will be very fast

Comment: And about "just teach developers to care about working copy hygiene" - sure. But always better to let computer do some work, that can be done by computer, than waste people's time.

Comment: @Ezh Computer cannot do this task obviously. Developer should do, and if he doesn't then he wastes time. E.g. if your working copy has a lot of binaries, local configs, temp files, and so on, how would git know that only these two files are actually new classes you just created and need to be commited?

Comment: As I said - by files extensions and by information from project file. If some ".cpp" file is present in Visual Studio project and not present under version control - it will definitely break a build of this project.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up pre-commit hooks with both Subversion and Git. These hooks are basically just shell scripts, and you can do very simple or very complex things with them.

- [Git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)
- [Subversion hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)

A few examples:

- A simple Git pre-commit hook that looks for uncommitted .cpp files:

  ```sh
  untracked_cpp_files=$(git ls-files --exclude-standard -o *.cpp)
  if [ -n "${untracked_cpp_files}" ]; then
    echo "Unable to commit: untracked .cpp files found in repository."
    exit 1
  fi
  ```
- Here's a Github project which provides a Git pre-commit hook to check the syntax of various languages: https://github.com/shadow7412/hooks.
- And a list of some helpful Subversion hooks: http://blog.grimsy.net/2008/07/a-few-svn-pre-commit-hooks/

Comment: Do you know some libraries of hooks scripts? Maybe some tool, containing things, I described in question?

Comment: I was able to find a few examples: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=git+hook+%28library+OR+functions%29. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a really good canonical library of functions you could use in hooks. Sky's the limit really: anything you could do in a script (bash, ruby, python, perl, etc.) you can do in a hook.

Comment: @Ezh I've added a few more links of things I know of or could find with searching, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Git has such a system :

```
man githooks
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It is way to set hook - I know about it, svn also has hooks. But I am talking about code in this hooks to do what I described in question.